# Value returned in recursive statement is different from what is calculated

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to calculate the square root of x using Newton's method. Everything works and a is equal to the square root of x right until I return it when it gives me back a completely different (always constant) number that is much larger.

```
int main()
{
    float newtonA;
    float newtonX = 35735;
    float epsilon = 0.001;

    newtonA = newtonX / 2;

    printf("\n********RECURSIVE NEWTON********\n");
    printf("The square root of %0.1f is: %0.2f\n", newtonX, newtonRec(newtonX, newtonA, epsilon));

    return 0;
}


float newtonRec (float x, float a, float eps)
{
    if (abs(a * a - x) <= eps )
    {
        printf("\n****%0.2f****\n", a);*/
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n***a: %.1f x: %.1f***\n", a, x);
        a = (a + x / a) / 2;
        newtonRec(x, a, eps);
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: `int abs(int j)` is for `int`.  Try `fabs()`.

Comment: Isn't there something missing in this line: `newtonRec(x, a, eps);`?

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
a = (a + x / a) / 2;
newtonRec(x, a, eps);
```

to

```
a = (a + x / a) / 2;
return newtonRec(x, a, eps);
```

```
> $./a.out
> ****189.04**** The square root of 35735.0 is: 189.04
```